# lm (linear regression) function generated un-removable outliers

Tags: r, lm

I have performed linear regression (lm) on two modified p-value types: q-value and Benjamini-Hochberg. Results gives two astronomical outliers, however, after removal of those, new outliers are always present. Could someone please replicate the code and see if issue prevails? What could be the possible source of an issue?

Here is the full code for easy copy/paste:

```
library(qvalue)

p = 50
m = 10
pval = c(rbeta(m,1,100), runif(p-m,0,1))

BHpval <- p.adjust(pval,method="BH")
qval_ <- qvalue(pval)
print(qval_$pi0)

fit2 <- lm(qval_$qvalues ~ BHpval)
plot(fit2)
```

Comment: please provide all necessary packages

Comment: added ```library(qvalue)```

Comment: Hmm. Statistically this doesn't make much sense to me. Why regress BH-adjusted p-values on q-values? Both sets of values derive from two different methods of correcting for multiple hypothesis testing. While there should be a correlation between both sets of adjusted p-values, using a fitted linear model to estimate outliers makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate on why you want to use such a model for outlier detection?

Comment: There shouldn't be any outliers, e.g. ```plot()``` function generates a straight line, as expected. lm() should work just fine, even if there isn't immediate application to outcome. Instead it generates unexplainable outliers.

Comment: The model (any model) does not *"generate unexplainable outliers"*. As I tried to explain, different multiple hypothesis testing correction methods will lead to different adjusted p-values. It's not trivial/possible to map adjusted p-values from one method to those from another method. Different methods may correct for different things (e.g. FDR, FWER etc.) and may make different assumptions. That's why I said fitting a (linear) model to BH-adjusted p-values and q-values makes no sense.

Comment: PS. I assume q-values refer to p-values adjusted for multiple hypothesis testing according to the method of John Storey, which is different from the method implemented by Benjamini-Hochberg.

Comment: Agree with @MauritsEvers, it's weird to regress one against the other. You can plot this plot(-log10(qval_$qvalues),-log10(BHpval)), they are extremely similar. And to add a side note, q-values are equivalent to BH when pi0 = 1

Comment: "Let’s examine the relationship between BH adjusted P-values and Storey’s Q-values. Generate p = 5000 P-values by command pval = c(rbeta(m,1,100), runif(p-m,0,1)) where m = 1000. (So here first m P-values come from the alternative distribution and the remaining p − m are from the null.)
Apply both BH adjustment (p.adjust(,method="BH")) and qvalue() to these P-values. Print out the estimate of π0 = p0/p given by qvalue.
Do linear regression of qvalues on BH-adjusted P-values. Compare the slope to the estimate of π0 from qvalue and explain why you see what you see."

Comment: Thats the problem i'm referring to.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435659/lm-linear-regression-function-generated-un-removable-outliers .. is this a homework question?